# Html Table Caption problem in conversion to pdf

Tags: itext7, pdfhtml

I am converting html to pdf by using HtmlConverter.convertToElements and then adding the iElements to the document. And it works with every html element except a caption element directly inside a table.

```
<table>
  <caption>Some text</caption>
  ... TRs with TDs here ...
</table>
```

The error is

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: FontProvider and FontSet are empty. 
Cannot resolve font family name (see ElementPropertyContainer#setFontFamily) 
without initialized FontProvider (see RootElement#setFontProvider).
```

I have identified that the error occurs at com.itextpdf.layout.renderer.TextRenderer.resolveFonts when the FontProvider has no fonts. It does not help to explicitly define the font for caption in a style and all other elements use the same font just fine. If I hide the caption by using display: none; everything else (h3, p, div, th, td) renders correctly in the pdf and uses the fonts just fine. It feels like something is wrong in iText, but a work-around would be welcome in the meantime.

I am using Linux, Java and itext7-core 7.2.3 and html2pdf 4.0.3

Comment: Please provide sample code to reproduce the problem

Comment: I am not really sure how much more you need in order to test? I this not enough?
<table><caption>Hello</caption><tr><td>Hi</td></tr></table>